# Swift: Cannot subscript a value of type '[UIViewController]?'

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to figure out how to fix this issue in Swift on Xcode 7 (iOS9) and I am also having this error:

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[UIViewController]?' with an index of type 'Int'

Any suggestion appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

My code:

```
func indexPositionForCurrentPage(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {

    let currentViewController = pageViewController.viewControllers[0] as UIViewController

    for (index, page) in pages.enumerate() {
        if (currentViewController == page) {

            return index
        }
    }

    return -1
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
let currentViewController = pageViewController.viewControllers![0]
```

It would be safer, though, to write:

```
if let currentViewController = pageViewController.viewControllers?[0] {
    // ... and then do everything else in the if-block
end
```

Another alternative:

```
guard let currentViewController = pageViewController.viewControllers?[0] else { 
    return 
}
// ... and then just proceed to use currentViewController here
```

This has the advantage that it's safe but there's no need to put the remainder of the function inside an `if` block.

Comment: Notice that there is no need to downcast any longer; Swift 2.0 knows that this is an array of UIViewControllers!

Comment: Also `pageViewController.viewControllers?.first` saves you from getting "index out of bounds" exceptions.