# Comparing UIViewController instances

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I am building an application with a customized tab bar. One of the button will not select the corresponding view controller and instead it will trigger some custom code (such as a modal opening).

I subclassed UITabBarController with the following:

```
import UIKit

class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        delegate = self
    }

    func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        if (viewController == self.viewControllers[2]) {
            return false
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

However, the comparison `viewController == self.viewControllers[2]` does not seem to work. I get the following error:

> Could not find an overload for `==` that accepts the supplied arguments

Being completely new to Swift, I couldn't find any material that explains how to compare specific instances of objects, or if this is the right way to do it at all.

How can I change this code to make it work?

Comment: Why did you subclass `UITabBarController`? To do this all you need to do is implement the delegate methods

Comment: I did it in order to be able to apply some custom styles to the bar. That code was redacted in my example, since it's not relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First** (to make it work): unwrap the `self.viewControllers`:

```
if (viewController == self.viewControllers![2]) {
    return false
}
```

To make it more safe, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30879094/2442804)

**Second** (to make it *right*): remove the unneeded parentheses, which apparently cause problems for the compiler:

```
if viewController == self.viewControllers![2] {
    return false
}
```

That way you would have actually received a more useful error message:

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[UIViewController]?' with an index of type 'Int'

which would given you a better hint what was wrong.

Comment: I see! I will have to look up unwrapping a bit more. Thanks!